# use a different directory as copy target

Tags: robocopy

hi I would like robocopy to output the actual copied files to a different directory than the one that it uses to determine the files to copy.

So i have 3 directories:

1. source
2. reference
3. output/diff-folder

Robocopy supports to only copy files that are older than in the target directory (or other filters) but i would keep this target directory (that I called reference) as is and just generate a difference folder.

So I would like to create a diff-folder. For easier deployment of small changes from large directory structures.

Comment: afaik robocopy has not such a function

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this natively with just robocopy, but you could do it with an extra step of simply copying the files to your target directory first, then calling robocopy.

If this doesn't work for you, you need to explain why you want to do this strange copying function and maybe we can help further.